# How to add "Read & execute" permission in Windows 7 for file on Samba drive

Tags: c, linux, windows, permissions, samba

From a C program I would like to add "Read & execute" permission in Windows 7 for a file on a Samba drive.  The "icacls" program is used in example below, but a C library call could also be a possibility if available.

The permissions can be changed for Windows users, for example Everyone, with the Windows "icacls" program (using system call), but when I try to change it for a Samba user, with name shown through Windows, then "icacls" returns:

```
U:\temp>icacls hello.exe /grant smbuser:RX
user: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

Any idea about how I can add "Read & execute" permission to a file in Windows so the Samba (Linux) user and groups will get the Linux "x" permission set ?

Comment: If you set the permissions you want on the Linux side, what does icacls then show?

Comment: icacls hello.exe gives information, but still says: `hello.exe No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. (R,W) No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. (RX)      Everyone:(RX)`  It looks like Windows allow command line control of permissions, even through GUI control is accepted.

Comment: Curious.  Try `cacls /s` and post the result here.

Comment: The system is Windows 7, thus `icacls` is used.  I got inspired by you comment, and tried to did deeper.  The Samba drive is connected with different credentials than the Win user, and it appears that Win7 won't allow the `icacls` command change the file permissions for the Samba users SID.   However, the GUI through "context menu => properties => security => permissions" allows change of permissions.  And I can even save/restore for Samba user (SID) with `icacls` afterwards.  But I can't just use the SID extracted from the `icacls ... /save ...`.  Hmm... any good ideas are appreciated :-)

Comment: Windows 7 still has `cacls`.  It's deprecated, but it's there.  But `icacls /save` does roughly the same thing (just a bit less convenient) so you should be able to see the SID in string form (S-1-something) for the Samba users.  `icacls` allows you to specify a string SID by prefixing it with an asterisk.

Comment: Good idea, but icacls won't accept the SID that I extracted from the /save file: `u:\temp>icacls hello.exe /grant *S-1-22-2-100:(rx)` `*S-1-22-2-100: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.` `Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files`  However, I can apply the /save file with /restore...  So maybe a solution is to create a file with /save, modify the file, and then apply with /restore...  Just a little annoying that something that can be done easily in a GUI can be so tricky in the CLI... but hey, it's Windows ;-)